# unique constraint (%s.%s) violated

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a problem with my procedure below. I have records for different item numbers (order numbers) that have been purchased a number of times. When I return part of the purchase based on the item number, it should delete the record from the `items` table and insert the item details into a table called `deleted_items'.The problem is when I delete part of the order once at a time, the table deleted_Items will come with this error:

> ORA-06512: at line 4
>   00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
>   *Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
>              For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
>              this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
>   *Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.

```
  create or replace PROCEDURE RET_Item(Item_no number(5))
           AS
       CURSOR Return_i
          IS
       SELECT * FROM Items
       WHERE item_num = Item_no
       AND Item_num IN (SELECT Item_num FROM deleted_items);
     cur1 Return_i%ROWTYPE;
   BEGIN    
   OPEN Return_i;
    LOOP
     FETCH Return_i INTO cur1;
    EXIT WHEN Return_i%NOTFOUND;
     IF cur1.Delivered IS NOT NULL THEN

     Insert into deleted_itmes values(
         cur1.Order_No,cur1.Item_num,cur1.Delivered,User,sysdate,   
           'Item_returned');

     DELETE FROM Items WHERE Item_num = Item_no ;
     DELETE FROM Purchase where Item_num = Item_no;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Item number ' || Item_no ||' deleted! ');
     ELSIF cur1.Delivered IS NULL THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cannot return item: '|| cur1.Item_num);
   END IF;
  END LOOP;
 CLOSE Return_i;
END RET_item;
```

Items Table

```
         Order_No      Item_num      Delivered   
        ----------    ----------     --------- 
           1001          1234        12-JUN-15           
           1002          5678        01-JAN-15  
           1003          9087        05-FEB-15
```

Purchase Table

```
             Order_No     Item_num     Quantity  
            ----------   ----------   --------------- 
               1001        1234           10
               1001        9087           7
               1002        9087           10 
               1003        1234           1 
               1003        5678           12
```

Deleted_Item Table

Items Table

```
      Order_No   Item_num    Delivered   Name_on-order  Date_of_Ret  Status
```

Comment: Can you post your DDL for the Items table?

Comment: I have updated my question, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your code, what table you are INSERTing into.. could you paste the whole INSERT statement?

If you are inserting into the DELETED_ITEMS table then why do you need the

```
AND Item_num IN (SELECT Item_num FROM deleted_items)
```

Shouldn't it be

```
AND Item_num NOT IN (SELECT Item_num FROM deleted_items)
```

Comment: Insert will be on deleted items! I have done the NOT IN, but the problem is when I have an order 1001 with an item Number let say 1234 which has two purchase 1111 and 2222. If the 1001 had deleted the purchase number 2222, the details of that order will be removed from Items table and will be inserted into deleted_Items table for that particular order. However if the order 1001want to delete the purchase of 1111, then this wouldn't be deleted because of the NOT IN in the subquery!

Comment: @Doodi - It is a bit unclear based from your comments above. Could you post the before and after snapshots of your data to clarify what is needed?

Comment: Ok, I am so sorry for not explaining myself very well but will include all the required and will update my question.

Comment: I have updated my question, I hope I explained myself

Comment: @Doodi, based on the data you showed the NOT IN should work as expected. Taking your example, if you have an order 1001 for Item 1234 in the ITEMS table which has 2 records in the PURCHASE table and no records in the DELETED_ITEMS table - When item_num 1234 is passed to the procedure, it will get 1 records from the cursor, it will then insert that record in the DELETED_ITEMS table, it will then delete 1 record in the ITEMS table and 2 records in the PURCHASE table for that item_num (1234). The next item you try to pass the same item_num, the cursor will return 0 records and exit the loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what if I want to delete  1003,  9087 from Items, and I already have a record of 1003 for a different purchase let's assume 9939! Therefore, the insert won't occur based on the previous record that has the same order_no 1003 as part of the primary key.

Comment: If we walk-thru this scenario, we pass 9087 as item_num to the stored procedure, it will enter the loop as 9087 is not yet in the DELETED_ITEMS table. It will then enter the loop and try to insert into DELETED_ITEMS table and at this point it will fail if the primary key on the DELETED_ITEMS table is only ORDER_NO.  I think the primary key on the DELETED_ITEMS table should be ORDER_NO + ITEM_NO. That should address the issue.

Comment: Yes, this was my point and I did make the ORDER_NO + ITEM_NO as primary keys! This is why the insert doesn't work as appropriate. This is my whole point of the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99605/discussion-between-vmachan-and-doodi).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99634/discussion-between-dodi-and-vmachan).

Comment: Hi, I made all the alterations by adding PNO to process_orders but didn't work

Comment: The same as before really! However, It doesn't look alright when the records inserted twice or more in the process orders table. Is there a method enable a user to return an order, then cancel another order using the same ONO, but it would notify the user wether all/ part of the orders returned or cancelled? !?

Comment: Strange that you are getting the unique constraint error again even after changing the primary key of the process orders to (ONO, PNO).. I think the way the tables are designed i.e. the order-to-details relation and then the order-to-parts relation have to be mirrored in the deleted_odetails and process_order table. The deleted_odetails and process_orders tables cannot be at the order level if only part of an order is cancelled or processed. Hence the process_orders table would have multiple records per order. You may need to re-think the entity relations to be more in-line with requirements

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I totally and entirely agree with you. The relations seem odd. However, my authority to change tables applied only on Process_Orders and Deleted_Odetails! I created the Deleted_Odetails based on the Odetails table! I've been instructed that those two tables share the same characteristics as all deleted orders should be stored in the deleted_odetails

Comment: Hi vmachan, I didn't solve the problem but I have now an error with the deleted_odetails!! The source of the error needs a chat if you don't mind!